# Why my subprocess STDOUT prints nothing under nohup

Tags: python, linux, unix, subprocess, nohup

I have a code executed the following way

```
$ python mycode.py param1 param2
```

It produces output using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) inside `mycode.py`:

```
import subprocess
paramlist = ['othercodes.py','infilel.txt']

p = subprocess.Popen(paramlist,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

# out is empty under nohup
print out
```

I have no problem getting the complete result using these commands:

```
 $ python mycode.py  > output.txt 
 $ python mycode.py   >> output.txt
```

But when I do one of this,  I get empty result in `output.txt`:

```
 $ nohup python mycode.py   > output.txt &
 $ nohup python mycode.py   >> output.txt &
 $ nohup python mycode.py   >> output.txt 2>&1
```

What's the correct way to do it?

**Update**:

I fixed the problem. As pointed by CharlesDuffy the problem is in `othercodes.py`.
In particular these lines:

```
        # # If there's input ready, do something, else do something
        # # else. Note timeout is zero so select won't block at all.

        # if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
        #     infile = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
        #     args.append(infile)
```

Once I commented out the last 3 lines, `mycode.py` then works fine.

Comment: What is it that "doesn't work"? How "incomplete" is it?

Comment: Provide a fully complete reproducer. The contents of `othercode.py` (can potentially) matter -- if it checks for whether the process has a controlling TTY, for instance. Depending on that external code but not providing it (or, better, providing the smallest possible code you can test to produce the same behavior) means there's no guarantee anyone else can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You're right.`othercodes.py` is the problem. It produces error when I do nohup on it. This is external code not made by me. Is there any way I can wrap that code so that it can print result on nohup?